# How to dynamically update user permissions on entities in ASP.NET Core using Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Identity to handle authentication in an ASP.NET Core project. I would like users who have the role "Admin" to modify the permissions (create, read, update and delete) of the users who have the role "User" on the access to the entities of the project. Can you help me by advising me a way to solve this problem? My permissions management page looks like this:

[capture of permissions management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOJOk.jpg)

Comment: How are you handling permissions?

Comment: For now, I am handling permissions with "Role-based authorization"

Comment: so you have one role per combination? Like ProductCreate, ProductUpdate, ProductDelete?  Is this how or you dont have any permissions at all?  Roles and permissions are not the same thing,  Please explain.

Comment: There is many ways to do this... Some people user claims and other ways.... I particularly created a website recently that does exactly this.   I created a class that derives from AuthorizationHandler<RolesAuthorizationRequirement>.  And have a custom rolestore that pulls the user "permissions".   This is a very complex problem to solve with a few lines of code.  It will require a lot of coding and testing.  I would sugest you start by creating the mentioned class and another class that derives from IRoleStore<T>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you were right, I confused roles and permissions.